# Scholastic fringe benefit doesn't actually do anything, right?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

It appears that the DMG II scholastic fringe benefit allows you take 20 on knowledge checks you are trained in in very specific circumstances.  Given you can take 20 any time you are not threatened or rushed and there are no major consequences for failure you could already do this.  Am I correct in thinking that the fringe benefit from the scholastic background provides literally no change to the normal rules for taking 20?  Does using the fringe benefit's take-20 ability negate the circumstance bonus you would normally get for researching in a library?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**You're wrong** because *there are* major consequences for failure: not being able to roll for that specific bit of knowledge again until you invest 1 more rank in the skill.
The SRD makes the consequences pretty clear:

> Try Again: No. The check represents what you know, and thinking about a topic a second time doesn’t let you know something that you never learned in the first place.

This means you can't normally take 20 on a knowledge roll.

Comment: You could add a link to http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/knowledge.htm and the magic phrase "Try Again:
No. The check represents what you know, and thinking about a topic a second time doesn’t let you know something that you never learned in the first place." to make this a fully sound answer.